Creating a task from a journey to salesforce
I'm trying to create a task in salesforce from my journey. Steps taken:

Created a Group/Queue in salesforce
Created a journey entry point being a data extension
Added the Object Activity

select object activity > Searched for tasks
select email user > Create New Record
Assigned ID to: group (created in sf)
Name ID: Marketing Cloud Attribute > Journey Data > ContactID




Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What is your question @Radford?

When I run the journey the task is not being created. Am I configuring something incorrectly?
